# Is there alternative if-else syntax without need for endif

Tags: mysql, if-statement

My problem is(was) the following.I was trying to use if else statement without end if and MySQL always gave me syntax error.Even though this code works I just did not like the concept that you "must" inform the system with writing end if to specify that if-else statement is over.Is there any other way to accomplish the same code without using end if?I was thinking about writing two separate if clauses instead of using if-else but I still had a syntax error.

Edit:I deleted the code since it made the question more complicated for some users.The basic question was to change the format of if else end if

Comment: It's not a concept, it's a syntax. Unfortunately, if you don't like it, there's not much you can do.

Comment: The `ELSE` is optional. The `THEN` and  `END IF` are mandatory. it's not a problem. Are you sure the procedure is working? There's references to procedure variables that aren't declared `max_helper` and `cur_budget`. And I've never seen procedure arguments qualified with the name of the procedure in a SQL statement. This looks like MySQL syntax, but I'm puzzled as to how this code is actually working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are alternatives to using an `IF` statement.

As an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE check_budget_sp(IN in_department_name VARCHAR(20)
  ,IN in_salary DECIMAL(8,2),OUT res VARCHAR(1))
BEGIN
  SET res = 'T';
  SELECT CASE WHEN d.max_budget>(d.cur_budget + in_salary) THEN 'F' ELSE 'T' END
    INTO res
    FROM department d
   WHERE d.dept_name = in_department_name
   LIMIT 1;
END$$
```

If the SELECT doesn't return a row, MySQL is going to throw a warning message. (The OP procedure pattern would exhibit the same behavior.) If we want to avoid a warning, we could easily do that, but it would require some additional code.

To emulate the **`then 'F' else 'T'`** logic in OP procedure, in case no row is returned by the query, we just initialize the return value to the value that would be returned by the `else`, before we run the query.

This implementation doesn't require any extra "helper" procedure variables. And the extra `SET` statement is only there to ensure that the procedure returns a 'T' or an 'F' (when the query doesn't return a row).
There are several other alternatives.

---

For a MySQL **`IF`** statement, the **`THEN`** and **`END IF`** are mandatory. The **`ELSE`** is optional.

It's not really a problem.

If you don't like the `END` required as part of the `CASE` expression, you could replace the `CASE` expression, with a MySQL specific function...

```
            IF(d.max_budget>(d.cur_budget + in_salary),'F','T')
```

Comment: If the query happens to return more than one row, MySQL would throw an error, not just a warning (I think). I added a `LIMIT 1` to the query, to guarantee that it won't return more than one row. (It's likely, that `dept_name` is expected to be unique in the `department` table. Absent a guarantee, I'm including the LIMIT. I'd also add an `ORDER BY` clause to make the result deterministic, but I omitted that just to avoid cluttering up the procedure with another line.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
if max_helper>(cur_budget + check_budget_sp.salary)  then
   set res="F";
else
   set res="T";               
end if;
```

Can be replaced by:

```
set res = if(max_helper > cur_budget + check_budget_sp.salary, 'F', 'T');
```

Comment: I don't see the `max_helper` or `cur_budget` variables declared. Is it valid to qualify a procedure argument with the name of the procedure? (Maybe I'm confused, but I don't see how this is going to compile or run.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I made no claims about working. I only proposed an alternative to the fragment asked about that meets the question's requirements

Comment: Your answer seems much more prettier but one question.Doesnt that make the result "T" when max_helper is bigger than the sum.Because in my code it needs to be "F"

Comment: @Curriculaa quite so (I got T and F reversed). I've amended the answer